# How to pass an object property as a parameter in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I know the below is possible in Javascript. Is there anything similar I can use in SwiftUI to pass an object property as a String?

```
var a = { foo: 123 };
a.foo    // 123
a['foo'] // 123
var str = 'foo';
a[str]   // 123
```

Comment: I think you can use dictionaries

Comment: `var a = { foo: 123 };` and `a.foo` are like a class/struct. `a['foo']` and `a[str]` look like dictionaries.

Comment: How would you use this in Swift? Can you give us some usage examples of you you'd want to use this feature?

Comment: Where is the SwiftUI in this question?

Answer (score 1):

What you likely want here is a key path. For example, given:

```
struct A {
    var foo: Int
}
```

You can construct an `A`, and access it:

```
let a = A(foo: 123)
a.foo // 123
```

And given that, you can access the `foo` property by key path:

```
let kp = \A.foo
a[keyPath: kp]  // 123
```

If your actual goal is to map strings to integer, that's just a `[String: Int]`, and it would work identically. If you mean "I want to pass strings to objects has have fairly random things happen, and possibly crash like they do in JavaScript," then that's also possible, using a custom subscript like `subscript(key: String) -> Int?`.